# Ubuntu - Cron job not completing in PHP script that contains include file

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I'm inserting a record into my DB each time the cron job runs my script and that works. When the PHP script reaches an include file, the functionality in the file doesn't execute. When I run the script in the browser it all works fine. Is it a cron permission issue to access the include file? I don't see an error in my Ubuntu cron log.

Comment: Errors in scripts aren't written to the cron log. `cron` normally sends the output as email.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out paths to includes in the PHP file need to be absolute. Adding "/var/www/html/filename.php" worked for me.

Comment: To make your code more portable, consider using `__DIR__` instead of hard-coding the path.